# DISPLAY env var for jvisualvm in Linux VM (Red hat 6.5)

Tags: java, linux

I'm getting the following error when I try to launch jvisualvm from the jdk

*Error: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0,0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.*

I've tried:
export DISPLAY=:0,0
export DISPLAY=localhost:0,0

Comment: Was this voted down because it is not strictly a coding issue?!  

Let me point out that this sort of problem is as annoying and needs an answer just as much because it restricts the investigation of a bug and is as much of an issue as any stack trace !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha - this worked export DISPLAY=:0